# Validate no other record exists without querying the db table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to write a rails activerecord validation that validates this new record will be the first and only record in the db table **WITHOUT** an additional query to the db in the validation.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base      
  validate :first_and_only_foo?
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  def first_and_only_foo?
    errors.add(:base, "another foo already exists") if something_that_doesnt_query_db
  end
end
```

So doing that ^ without any of this in the validation ...

```
MyTable.first.present?
```

Any ideas?

I've read through the [docs on validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) (maybe i missed something) but I don't see anything that would pertain to this usecase.

If there's some `validates :name` way of going about this I'd be interested to know what that might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`uniqueness`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validation, but it will perform a query under the hood. What you are suggesting does not exist in Rails out of the box. There is a lifecycle of events in ActiveRecord that takes place when you create or update an object, and validations are just one part (initialization, validations, callbacks, etc...).

You can write a method that would rescue a database uniqueness constraint, but I honestly don't know why you would want to do that. The added complexity is not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Since it's not possible, i realized my code above wouldn't really work anyways because the validate I wrote prevents a record from being updated which wasn't desired. I would need to have used a before_create instead.